# What will be the query in oracle?

Tags: oracle

How to write this sql query into Oracle.

```
ALTER TABLE student MODIFY 'student_balance' DOUBLE(20,5)
```

As i am new in oracle so can anybody suggest some good sites to learn oracle queries again

Comment: That's DDL, not a sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Use number instead of double

```
  Alter table student MODIFY student_balance number(20,5)
```

For more refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm) .

Comment: Thanx tarun but there is some double precision is there in Oracle. Can i use that also? I mean whats the difference

Comment: See docs here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330 but briefly if you want to store numbers for which 3 / 2 is never going to be something silly like 1.4999999999999999, then use NUMBER. Typically Oracle developers use NUMBER for everything by default because the arithmetic is more accurate, and there are not decimal numbers that cannot be represented in NUMBER. You would only stray to the binary types for very good reasons.